# Get message in Java code ( Spring 3 )

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties, annotations, message

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="messages" />
```

bean and obviously in my velocity files I can use #springMessage() to get needed message. But what if I want to get that message in my *.java controller? Is there some annotation that I can use like ?

```
@Annotation('message')
private String message;
```

Or I need to do it in different way?

Thanks

Comment: Does this have to be internationalized, or do you just have a single `messages.properties` file?

Comment: At this moment I got just one messages.properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need any internationalization, then you can use the `messages.properties` file with a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` (see the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)), along with the `@Value` annotation

In XML:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="locations" value="classpath:messages.properties"/>
</bean>
```

And in Java:

```
@Value('message')
private String message;
```

You'll also need `<context:annotation-config/>` to make this work (see [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config))

Comment: ok, that's a good solution, but what if my messages.properties file will grow and grow? How does it work? Does the content of my file is stored somewhere ( and I think this won't be a good solution then ) or in PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer bean I just show where to look for a current messages?

Comment: @Dawid: What does it matter if it grows?  The annotation just refers to a single entry in the file.